# How to recover music albums as a whole after iTunes split them

Tags: itunes, import, compact-disc

I imported my CDs into my iTunes library but it was not able to understand that the CDs were to be imported each as a whole.

So now, I have many split albums, for various causes: duets, errors in the strings (but weren't they provided by Gracenote?).

What have I to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was posted on the [Apple Discussion site](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1124296?start=0&tstart=0) also.

> I found this elsewhere on the Apple.com site: select all the songs
>   that are scattered. Right-click/Get Info.....you'll see towards the
>   bottom a field called Compilation. Select Yes.

Answer (score 1):

HOW TO MERGE AN ALBUM THAT HAS BEEN SPLIT:

Search “MY MUSIC", using “ARTISTS” to locate the split album.  When listed by artist, the split album listings are shown consecutively, one right next to the other.

Highlight the first song of the first album and then SHIFT/HIGHLIGHT to include the last song of the album to be merged.

Right click on highlighted area and select “GET INFO.”  Ignore prompt regarding multiple items.  “Get Info” will immediately show the correct screen by default, which is the “DETAILS" screen.

The line item, “ALBUM” will be listed as “mixed.”  Change this to the correct name of the album.

Select OK

The screen will rearrange its presentation and merge the split albums into a single album, showing the separated songs in their correct position.